# "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, pip

Я попытался установить discord.py .При скачивании питона ставил галочку над Add to PATH , пробовал переустановить pip, переустанавливал питон

Comment: откройте cmd, cd путь_к_папке_с_питоном, затем переходите в папку Scripts, теперь пишите pip install ...

Answer (score 2):

Нужно проверить, что в ваш `PATH` были добавлены пути папки `C:\path\to\python\Scripts` (для win). Именно в ней располагаются исполняемые файлы скриптов, такие как `easy_install` и `pip`.

Для **Windows** это можно сделать так:

```
> set PATH
```

Вы получите список путей через `;`.

Расширить переменную можно следующим образом:

```
> setx PATH="%PATH%;C:\path\to\python\Scripts"
```

Для **Linux** эта команда будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```sh
$ echo $PATH
```

Вы получите список путей через `:`.

Расширить переменную можно следующим обазом:

```sh
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pip
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня сработало только с аргументом `/M`:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python\Scripts" /M
```